# Get data from complex Json structure using NodeJs

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

json Structure:

```
    {
    "id" : "1",
    "Data" : [
    {
            "name" : "abc",

        },
        {
            "name" : "option1",
            "position" : [
                {
                    "name" : "option1",
                    "status" : [
                        {
                            "code" : "0",
                            "value" : "OFF"
                        },
                        {
                            "code" : "1",
                            "value" : "ON"
                        }
                    ]
                }]
        }   ]   
}
```

Here,I want to get the data from above complex Json structure.How to do that,
Have tried below code but giving error like; 
error: uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

```
function myfunc(req,res){
var collectionname  = db.collection("col1");
collectionname.find({}).each(function(err, doc) {
   if(doc != null)
    {
        var fdata = [];
        for(var i =0;i<doc.Data.length;i++){
            fdata.push(doc.Data[i].position.status);
            }
        console.log("fdata............",fdata);
    }
});
}
```

Please help with the same.

Comment: Position is an array, so can't access it using position.status. You can use position[0].status if there is only one object in the position array

Comment: `doc.Data[i].position` is an array

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: @TB.M `doc.Data[i].position[0].status` But you need to think a bit about this. The fact that it's an array means that it can contain any number (including 0) of objects with or without a `status` property. Can you be sure there's always at least one object? If there are more than one, can you be sure the first one is always the one you want?

Comment: yeah,It will not always 0 element,I hav updated the array in question and below i got the answer also.Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use foreach for prevent length undefined.

```
function myfunc(req,res)
{
    let collectionname = db.collection("col1");
    collectionname.find({}).each(function(err, doc)
    {
        if(doc != null)
        {
            let fdata = [];

            for(let i in doc.Data)
            {
                for(let j in doc.Data[i].position)
                {
                    fdata.push(doc.Data[i].position[j].status);
                }
            }

            console.log("fdata............", fdata);
        }
    });
}
```

@MikaelLennholm have right, `for(let i in doc.Data)` works but not recommanded, be careful not to use it in prototyped or object-built arrays.

---

**EDIT:**

```
function myfunc(req,res)
{
    db.collection('col1').find({}).each(function(err, doc)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log('[INFOS] Request fail, more details:\n', err);
        }
        else if(doc)
        {
            let fdata = [];

            if(doc.Data && doc.Data.length)
            {
                for(let i = doc.Data.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if(doc.Data[i].position && doc.Data[i].position.length)
                    {
                        for(let j = doc.Data[i].position.length-1; j >= 0; j--)
                        {
                            if(doc.Data[i].position[j].status)
                            {
                                fdata = fdata.concat(doc.Data[i].position[j].status);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log("[INFOS] Datas:\n", fdata);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: And if we want to include name along with status .how we can do?

Comment: NEVER use `in` for arrays, it's going to cause weird bugs

Comment: Than,how we can archive the result?

Comment: I m using In but it is not iterating,,I want to iterate the array ??How we can do that ?

Comment: For add name, you can just edit `fdata.push(doc.Data[i].position[j].status);` by `fdata.push(doc.Data[i].position[j]);`

Comment: `console.log(i)` return string 0, 1, 2... So you can add count variable or `console.log(parseInt(i))` bbut not recommanded.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm, you can use `in` for a simple datas array. But be careful not to use it in prototyped or object-built arrays.

Comment: @Liberateur It should never be used for arrays unless you have complete control of every single line of JS code that runs on the page. A JS library or any other 3rd party script used on the page might extend `Array.prototype` which will break your loops. Best just to avoid it all together.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm, yes you're right, my habits are not those of others. I hate to use libs that change that and I'm not used to working with them.

Comment: yes using in is giving me repeated value..How to avoid that

Comment: Ok i edit my post. I use `concat` for prevent array in array. With `push` function : `[[{"code":"0","value":"OFF"},{"code":"1","value":"ON"}],[{"code":"0","value":"OFF"}]]`, with `concat` function : `[{"code":"0","value":"OFF"},{"code":"1","value":"ON"},{"code":"0","value":"OFF"}]`

Comment: can u invite me on chat so i can explain u better?

Answer (score 1):

im a newbie at nodejs, hope this's correctly

```js
//I assume this is a object or you can convert from string to object
var data = {
    "id": "1",
    "Data": [
        {
            "name": "option1",
            "position": [
                {
                    "name": "option1",
                    "status": [
                        {
                            "code": "0",
                            "value": "OFF"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": "1",
                            "value": "ON"
                        }
                    ]
                }]
        }]
}

var statusArr = data.Data[0].position[0].status;
console.log(...statusArr);
```

Result: `{ code: '0', value: 'OFF' } { code: '1', value: 'ON' }`

Comment: but same way I am doing it is not happening..If u check in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Parse through position array as well

```
function myfunc(req,res){
var collectionname  = db.collection("col1");
collectionname.find({}).each(function(err, doc) {
   if(doc != null)
    {
        var fdata = [];

        for(var i =0;i<doc.Data.length;i++){
        for(var j =0;j<doc.Data[i].position.length;j++){
            fdata.push(doc.Data[i].position[j].status);
            }
        }
        console.log("fdata............",fdata);
    }
```

});
}

Comment: error: uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: is position array always,